# `/home/webapp` is not a directory - Elastic Beanstalk (RAILS)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, ruby-on-rails-5, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy a Rails 5 app to Elastic Beanstalk but I am getting the following error in my log file that appears to indicate that my home directory is not properly set.

I tried setting the `HOME` environment variable by setting `HOME` to `~/my-app-name` but I have had no luck and it doesn't appear to be using the variable anyway. I set the variable under the software section in the environment configurations.

`/var/log/eb-activity.log`:

```
+ cd /var/app/ondeck
+ su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec 
/opt/elasticbeanstalk/support/scripts/check-for-rake-task.rb assets:precompile' webapp
`/home/webapp` is not a directory.
Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler/home/webapp' as your home directory temporarily.
+ '[' false == true ']'
+ su -s /bin/bash -c 'bundle exec rake assets:precompile' webapp
`/home/webapp` is not a directory.
Bundler will use `/tmp/bundler/home/webapp' as your home directory temporarily.
rake aborted!
Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): did not find expected alphabetic or numeric 
character while scanning an alias at line 83 column 22
/var/app/ondeck/config/environments/production.rb:96:in `block in <top (required)>'
/var/app/ondeck/config/environments/production.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
/var/app/ondeck/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace) (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)
```

I found a a similar issue here: [issue deploying rails 5 application to AWS using Elastic Beanstalk due to rb-readline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46919232/issue-deploying-rails-5-application-to-aws-using-elastic-beanstalk-due-to-rb-rea)

I also asked another question yesterday about the `psych` error (posted link below) but I am beginning to think that this error may be caused due to the invalid reference to `HOME`. I'm rather lost at this point and have been working on this for several hours with absolutely no luck.

Another question I posted yesterday about the psych error:
[Error Deploying on Elastic Beanstalk - Rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53937817/error-deploying-on-elastic-beanstalk-rails/53943338#53943338)

Comment: You wrote "another question" and "other question", but I don't see any question here. What is your question?

Comment: @sawa https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53937817/error-deploying-on-elastic-beanstalk-rails/53943338#53943338

Comment: I think this issue is related to the psych error.  I do not modify the home directory for my Rails deploys with elastic beanstalk and I receive the same warning in the eb-activity log file but it has never caused any problems.

Answer (score 3):

Ruby: 2.7.0
Rails: 6.0.2.1
Solidus: v2.10.0

Just add the "commands" section below to your `.ebextensions/packages.config`

Add required commands:

```
# Setup linux packages
option_settings:
  - option_name: BUNDLE_DISABLE_SHARED_GEMS
    value: "1"
  - option_name: BUNDLE_PATH
    value: "vendor/bundle"

packages:
  yum:
    git: []
    ImageMagick: []
    ImageMagick-devel: []
    openssl-devel: []
    postgresql93-devel: []

commands:
  01_node_get:
    # run this command from /tmp directory
    cwd: /tmp
    # flag -y for no-interaction installation
    command: 'curl --silent --location https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_8.x | sudo bash -'

  02_node_install:
    # run this command from /tmp directory
    cwd: /tmp
    command: 'sudo yum -y install nodejs'

  03_yarn_get:
    # run this command from /tmp directory
    cwd: /tmp
    # don't run the command if yarn is already installed (file /usr/bin/yarn exists)
    test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/yarn ] && echo "yarn not installed"'
    command: 'sudo wget https://dl.yarnpkg.com/rpm/yarn.repo -O /etc/yum.repos.d/yarn.repo'

  04_yarn_install:
    # run this command from /tmp directory
    cwd: /tmp
    test: '[ ! -f /usr/bin/yarn ] && echo "yarn not installed"'
    command: 'sudo yum -y install yarn'

  05_home_dir:
    test: '[ ! -p /home/webapp ] && echo "webapp not exited"'
    command: 'sudo mkdir -p /home/webapp'

  06_grant_home_dir:
    test: '[ ! -p /home/webapp ] && echo "webapp not exited"'
    command: 'sudo chmod 777 /home/webapp'
```

source: *https://medium.com/@tranduchanh.ms/deploy-and-manage-production-rails-5-app-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk-3efb0dfe021a*